# "cannot find file specified" error

Tags: server2go

When I try to run server2Go.exe, I get "The system cannot find file specified." error. And it does not run.

Which file is it looking for? I suppose it is iexplorer.exe but I want to be sure and I wonder where it is trying to find this file?

Answer (score 0):

It's been long time I don't use Windows but as far as I can remember, FileMon utility should help you. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no spaces in the path where you are running it from. I have noticed if the path is C:/my dir/my folder/ the space will cause this issue. Try it with C:/myfolder/ and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the launch browser needs to be changed. By default Server2Go tries to launch Internet Explorer (which many of us do not use). To change this the "BrowserType" line of the pms_config.ini file needs to be changed to whichever browser you want to use.